# How do I create a fakeapplication with an inmemory database in java play 2.5?

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

In order to do some functional tests, a fake application is required to run. In order to make all tests independent the fake application needs to use a clean database every time a test is setup. In order to do so, I found on the documentation that the ideal way is to use a inmemory database like this:

```
@Before
public void before() {
    app = fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase());
    start(app);

    initializeData();
}

@After
public void after() {
    stop(app);

}
```

The problem with this is that it does not set the MODE to MYSQL, since the normal database is a MYSQL database. In order to set this mode, one must add options. Which is done using the code below. Note that "test" is the name for the database (different than "default" to avoid confusion).

```
app =fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase("test", ImmutableMap.of("MODE", "MYSQL")));
```

However this code does weird stuff: it uses the default database (which is not even an inmemory database) configured in application.conf So then I changed the code to following:

```
app =fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase("default", ImmutableMap.of("MODE", "MYSQL")));
```

But this does nothing: It still says that MODE MYSQL is not set.

Can someone help me?

For the framework java play 2.5 is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some help from the documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTestingWithDatabases.

Comment: I tried that too, but I had trouble connecting to the database. I used         app =fakeApplication(ImmutableMap.of("db.default.url",database.getUrl(),"db.default.driver","org.h2.Driver","db.default.username","","db.default.password","")); and the code provided in the documentation but the database is not set to MYSQL as it crashes with " Syntax error in SQL statement "[*]#"